# How does CSS :first-child selector works

Tags: html, css

I have this html snippet:

```
<form class="job-manager-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">



  <fieldset>
    <label>Have an account?</label>
    <div class="field account-sign-in">
      <a class="button" href="">Sign in</a>

    </div>
  </fieldset>


  <!-- Job Information Fields -->

  <fieldset class="fieldset-job_title">
    <label for="job_title">Job Title</label>
    <div class="field required-field">
      <input type="text" class="input-text" required="">
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="fieldset-job_location">
    <label for="job_location">Location <small>(optional)</small></label>
    <div class="field ">
      <input type="text" class="input-text" name="job_location" id="job_location" placeholder="e.g. &quot;London&quot;" value="" maxlength="">
      <small class="description">Leave this blank if the location is not important</small> </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="fieldset-application">
    <label for="application">Application email/URL</label>
    <div class="field required-field">
      <input type="text" class="input-text" name="application" id="application" placeholder="Enter an email address or website URL" value="" maxlength="" required="">
    </div>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

And I would like to select first fieldset in the form. This what I am doing:

```
form.job-manager-form:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

But it selects all fieldset elements. How does :first-child works?

JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/uycop55x/).

Comment: `first-child` will modify the preceding element *if that element is the first child of its parent*. By doing `form.job-manager-form:first-child`, you're saying "Where job-manager-form is the first child, change its background to red". So, being that it's the first thing on the page, the entire form's background will be red.

Comment: You are using fieldset incorrectly. A fieldset groups a **set of fields**, should have  a `<legend>` to describe the set, and each field within it should have a `<label>` to describe the specific field. e.g. `<fieldset><legend>Favourite radio button</legend><input id="a" name="foo" value="1"><label for="a">This one</label><input id="b" name="foo" value="2"><label for="b">This other one</label></fieldset>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the element you want and then say it's the first-child.

There is an excellent article explaining how these selectors works:

[useful-nth-child-recipies](https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/)

```css
fieldset:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form class="job-manager-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <fieldset>
    <label>Have an account?</label>
    <div class="field account-sign-in">
      <a class="button" href="">Sign in</a>

    </div>
  </fieldset>


  <!-- Job Information Fields -->

  <fieldset class="fieldset-job_title">
    <label for="job_title">Job Title</label>
    <div class="field required-field">
      <input type="text" class="input-text" required="">
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="fieldset-job_location">
    <label for="job_location">Location <small>(optional)</small></label>
    <div class="field ">
      <input type="text" class="input-text" name="job_location" id="job_location" placeholder="e.g. &quot;London&quot;" value="" maxlength="">
      <small class="description">Leave this blank if the location is not important</small> </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="fieldset-application">
    <label for="application">Application email/URL</label>
    <div class="field required-field">
      <input type="text" class="input-text" name="application" id="application" placeholder="Enter an email address or website URL" value="" maxlength="" required="">
    </div>
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fieldset:first-child {
  background-color: red;
 }
```

This will work. However, your first-child fieldset is set to display:none; so it will not actually show the background color.

Answer (score 0):

It selects an element if it is the first child of its parent.

Your selector doesn't select any fieldsets. It selects the form.

The fieldsets have a (default) transparent background, so you can see the red through them.

To select the fieldset that is the first child of a form you would need:

```
form.job-manager-form > fieldset:first-child
```